# Mathematical induction in a limit problem

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, induction

This is a solution present in the book Mathematical Induction
A powerful and elegant method of proof.
]
I didn't quite understand the use of $L_n - nL_{n-1}$ in $(***)$

Problem 9.2.4. Prove that for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}, n\geq1$, one has

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{n ! x^{n}-\sin (x) \sin (2 x) \ldots \sin (n x)}{x^{n+2}}=\frac{n(2 n+1)}{36} \cdot n ! \text {. }
$$

Solution. We shall prove that the limit is well defined for each $n \geq 1$ while we are finding the suitable recurrence relation.

Let $L_{n}$ be the corresponding limit to $n \geq 1$. For $n=1$, we have by repeated application of L'Hôpital's rule that

$$
L_{1}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x-\sin (x)}{x^{3}}=\frac{1}{6}
$$

Also, one has

$$
\begin{aligned}
L_{n}-n L_{n-1} & =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{n x \sin (x) \ldots \sin (x(n-1))-\sin (x) \sin (2 x) \ldots \sin (n x)}{x^{n+2}} (***) \\
& =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \cdot \frac{\sin (2 x)}{x} \ldots \frac{\sin ((n-1) x)}{x} \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{n x-\sin (n x)}{x^{3}} \\
& =(n-1) ! \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{n-n \cdot \cos (n x)}{3 x^{2}} \\
& =n ! \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{n \sin (n x)}{6 x} \\
& =n ! \cdot \frac{n^{2}}{6} .
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore we have $L_{n}=n L_{n-1}+n ! \cdot \frac{n^{2}}{6}$.

We now prove by induction the statement

$$
P(n): \quad L_{n}=\frac{n(2 n+1)}{36} \cdot(n) !
$$

For $n=1$ we proved the result above, since $\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 !}{36}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Assume now that $P(n-1)$ is true. From the above recurrence we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
L_{n} & =n \cdot \frac{(n-1)(2 n-1) \cdot n !}{36}+\frac{n^{2} \cdot n !}{6}=\frac{n ! \cdot n}{36}[(n-1)(2 n-1)+6 n] \\
& =\frac{n ! \cdot n(n+1)(2 n+1)}{36}=\frac{n(2 n+1)}{36}(n+1) ! .
\end{aligned}
$$

This establishes the induction step and completes our proof.

Answer (score 2):

That proof is flawed indeed, because assuming that $P(n-1)$ is true, what we get is
$$L_n=n \cdot \frac{(n-1)(2 n-1) \cdot\color{red}{(n-1)!}}{36}+\frac{n^{2} \cdot n !}6,$$
not
$$L_n=n \cdot \frac{(n-1)(2 n-1) \cdot n !}{36}+\frac{n^{2} \cdot n !}6.
$$

Actually, the claim itself is wrong, as you can notice for instance for the base case $n=1$.
The correct formula is
$$L_n=\frac{n(2n+1)}{36}\color{red}{(n+1)!},$$
as can be either found directly, or proved by induction along the following lines:
$L_1=\frac16=\frac{1 \cdot 3}{36}\color{red}{2!}$ and
$$n\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{36}n!+n!\frac{n^2}6=\frac{n!n}{36}\left((n-1)(2n-1)+6n\right)\\=\frac{n(2n+1)}{36}(n+1)!.$$

Comment: So, reformulating we have this: $\displaystyle\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{n ! x^n-\sin (x) \sin (2 x) \cdots \sin (n x)}{x^{n+2}}=\dfrac{n(2 n+1)}{36} \cdot (n+1)!.$

Comment: This is not a reformulation, it is exactly what I wrote (your left hand side is what was called $L_n$, from the beginning of your post).